# Is it appropriate to give different ways of solving a problem?

Tags: discussion, comments, answers, accepted-answer

I was wondering if I felt someone had an XY problem (they have problem X but they go about it with Y and ask about Y rather than X), would it be appropriate to post an answer talking about a different way of going about a problem or would you comment first to clarify with the author of the question?

I've seen mixed experiences where someone was doing a problem one way, people suggested different solutions and they get downvoted because the author wanted it in that specific way.

I guess an example I had (kinda a while ago but it has come up and I want to make sure I'm going about it the right way) was this person was trying to find a way to direct users from one website via Javascript to other sites. I suggested in my answer that he should consider using `header` in `PHP` and some people commented that he specifically wanted Javascript while others said that it is appropriate to put these.

Thoughts on this? Wish I could find the question I answered. But I'm sure this has come up more than once. Thank you! Just trying to get more perspective.

Comment: Here are all your answers: http://stackoverflow.com/users/1168661/aug?tab=answers

Comment: Thank you Oded. I was looking through but I couldn't find it. I'm suspecting the question might have gotten deleted? I'll post it if I can find it. It wasn't a huge debate but I thought it was a question worth discussing.

Comment: It may have been... these things happen and only 10k+ users will be able to see it if it was indeed deleted.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could do either. There is no real fast rule here.

There is greater value to the community with the first approach - suggesting different ways and weighing the pros and cons.

Don't forget that when answering a question, you are trying to give a valuable answer to the whole community, not just the question OP.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I kind of wanted to clarify the use of comments though because on one hand, I could comment and let the OP know that I think there is a better solution and then properly answer his question, or I could just answer it straight away. Thanks for your thoughts!

Comment: @aug - That's my point. It really depends on the question and your mood at the time... Sometimes a clarification is appropriate (say if a large number of different options exist and clarification will narrow down the field), sometimes a great answer will include the best options and why.

Answer (score 2):

As Oded pointed out - yes, it's good to provide other solutions. Often people haven't actually realised that they could fix their issue with a design-change.

However - if somebody is explicitly asking for a particular language, that generally forms part of the constraint of their question. Most people are generally stuck with using only those languages they are *allowed* to use on any given project.

Think of a language as a (generally) non-negotiable constraint. Recommending a language change, in that circumstance, is thus considered Not a Solution to the question, as-provided - which is a perfectly understandable reason for the answer to get down-voted.